# XenServer 6.2 to 6.5 - rebuild servers?

Tags: xenserver

It appears the XenServer 6.5 has been released and it's quite a bit faster than 6.2 in many ways.

When I installed 6.2 I accepted the various defaults and end up with a system that is awkwardly partitioned. Root is rather small (and perpetually running out of space) while a 250Gb partition sits empty. To this end I'm thinking about doing a rebuild with v6.5.

I've been reading about the process and apparently you can't mix 6.2 and 6.5 in the same pool. If I take the pool members (3) out one at a time, rebuild them and put them in a new pool can I move the various VMs over?

---

EDIT:

To upgrade XenServer from 6.2 to 6.5 - start with the pool master and work your way through each server. If you've done a repartition you don't have to do the editing steps again - as long as you select 'upgrade' during the 6.5 install it won't repartition the disks.

Comment: FWIW - [here](https://major.io/2012/01/13/xenserver-6-disable-gpt-and-get-a-larger-root-partition/) is a link on how to set the root partition size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pool master and servers in the pool need to be the same XenServer version. To answer your question, yes you can remove one server at a time, upgrade, join the pool, then migrate the VM's. As always, make sure you make a backup first (export snapshots) before performing the upgrade.

Comment: So the process would be 1) rolling upgrade -> 2) pull each machine out, rebuild and then rejoin? Or should I do 2) -> 1)?

Comment: I've always exported the VMs out to separate storage, performed the upgrade, joined the pool, then import the VMs back. I'm sure you could do Steps 1-2-3 as you mention above, however I have not personally done that in a production environment.